# ActiveAndroid 'IN' clause

Tags: android, sqlite, activeandroid

I am developing an android app which works with the ActiveAndroid ORM.

I am looking for a simple query to get the list of Models from a list of ids. but I couldn't find the solution.

With a field `List<Long> ids`, how can I get my `List<MyModel.cass>`.

I tried, without success.

```
String concatIds = "(1,2,3,4)";
new Select().from(MyModel.class).where("Id in ?",concatIds).execute();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am searching for a solution for this as well. This is the best result that I have found so far: https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/issues/392

Answer (score -1):

new Select().from(MyModel.class).where("Id in (1,2,3,4)").execute();

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?